# Not allowed to load local resource, Chrome Server

Tags: google-chrome, security, localhost

I'm getting the following error when attempting to include a local image in my project:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///localhost:8887/assets/MIB.jpg%20alt=MIB

My Google & Stack Overflow searches led me to believe I could get around this security error if I downloaded the Chrome server to port 8887.  So I did this but the error persists.  Can someone advise?

Thank you.

Comment: OK, I see the partial answer to my own question. I'm still running the Angular Live Development Server except now on port 8887.

How do I run the Chrome server instead?

Comment: When I compile my Angular app, it automatically fires up the Angular Live Development server.  The documentation is poor as to how to start the Chrome server, and I have no experience with switching local servers.

Comment: Well, I think it sucks that Chrome blocks Angular developers from including images on their websites.  I don't understand it.